# Can not import CSV file in Spyder using read_csv, ValueError: Only callable can be used as callback

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spyder

This is my code. I am trying to import my dataset that is in the same directory I am working in, but it gives me ValueError.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Importing Dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
```

**Error with full traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-7b10dca7f8e2>", line 6, in <module>
    dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")

  File "C:\Users\saraj\anaconda3\envs\AI project\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\saraj\anaconda3\envs\AI project\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 460, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\saraj\anaconda3\envs\AI project\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1213, in read
    df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)

  File "C:\Users\saraj\anaconda3\envs\AI project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 468, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\saraj\anaconda3\envs\AI project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 259, in init_dict
    if missing.any() and not is_integer_dtype(dtype):

  File "C:\Users\saraj\anaconda3\envs\AI project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 11580, in logical_func
    return self._reduce(

  File "C:\Users\saraj\anaconda3\envs\AI project\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4248, in _reduce
    with np.errstate(all="ignore"):

  File "C:\Users\saraj\anaconda3\envs\AI project\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_ufunc_config.py", line 436, in __enter__
    self.oldcall = seterrcall(self.call)

  File "C:\Users\saraj\anaconda3\envs\AI project\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_ufunc_config.py", line 308, in seterrcall
    raise ValueError("Only callable can be used as callback")

ValueError: Only callable can be used as callback
```

Please help me understand what is happening here and how to solve it?

Comment: did you try to write the full path to the file instead of just the name?

Comment: Looks like it's having problems with some type conversion.  I don't think we can help you without some information about the csv file and its contents.  I can't guess how much we need to see.

Comment: I think the csv file might be corrupted. try making a copy of the same and try reading it.

Comment: I had to restart Spyder. The issue occured for reading and writing a CSV file through pandas.

Answer (score 0):

When your .csv has corrupted data that error might be, obtained.
The solution for that is,

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv",dtype=str)
```

Sometimes, it resolves the problem. Because the data might be in a different format from the one which you're trying to read. Or sometimes there might be inconsistencies in "delimiter". So, please check data accordingly and it might solve your problem.